# Why is the direction of a flame is always upward?

Tags: thermodynamics

why a candle's flame direction is always upward? What is the coposition of fire?
Don't say it's energy. There is something else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flames with no gravity?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46327/)

Comment: Why are you opposed to the answer being energy? Energy tends to drive everything, especially in thermodynamics. Motion, light, radiation (the sensation of heat) -- all energy.

Answer (score 2):

The direction of fire is whatever way the wind is blowing.  Seriously.  In a calm location, the heated air goes upwards.

As to the composition: it's a bit tricky. The simple bit is that various molecules produced during combustion (usually oxidation) are very energetic, and shortly after combustion, they cool off by emitting photons.  If you look closely, you'll see that the visible flame is not in contact with the burning material but just above it.

There's more, but I'm no expert.

Comment: I'm not expert either, but I would add that the light comes, at least in part, from photons emitted during those chemical reactions.  That's why flames from different materials have different colors.

Comment: @garyp good point.

Answer (score 2):

A candle flame points upwards because flame is extremely hot, and thus less dense than air (by a routine approximation using the [Ideal Gas Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law)), and thus rises.

A hot air ballon floats for the exact same reason.

As mentioned in the ["possible duplicate" question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46327/), this effect disappears in the absence of gravity.