# Why do a flame point upwards?

Tags: thermodynamics

Why do a candle's flame always point upwards opposite to gravitational force? Why does not it point sideways or upwards?

Comment: We expect that people asking questions here will have done at least [the obvious search](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=flame+upwards) to see if their question already has an answer. In this case it does.

Comment: It doesn't _point_ upward, it _moves_ upward.  A candle flame is not a thing that just sits there, it's a jet of moving gas.  Try this:  Put a candle a few feet in front of a white card or screen, and then shine a bright, point-like light toward it from some distance away (e.g., a small LED flashlight).  Look closely at the shadow on the screen, and see if you can't discern the motion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the direction of a flame is always upward?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103584/)